# function is not working when I call it

Tags: c++, random

I am having an issue with the actual program. after the user chooses either 1 or 2 to play against computer or human the next line that shows is "it's a draw" it skips the whole game. I am not sure why because I set turnNum to 0 and increment by 1 at the beginning of the while loop, and it should only be a draw game if turnNum is equal to 10. is my code incorrect?

```
/*
   Template for TicTacToe.cpp (CS-509 Assignment 5)

   Fill in the rest of this comment block.
*/


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
   Game status enumeration
*/
enum Status { WIN, DRAW, CONTINUE, QUIT };


/*
   Function prototypes
*/
// showBoard: Show current state of board
void showBoard( const char board[], int boardSize );
// checkGameState: Returns WIN or CONTINUE
Status checkGameState( const char board[] );
int getHumanSquare( const char board[] );
int getComputerSquare( const char board[] );
// checkBadSquare: Checks to see if a chosen square is already taken; returns
//                 true if already taken; used by getHumanSquare and
//                 getComputerSquare functions above.
bool checkBadSquare( const char board[], int squareNum );
int getrandint( int min, int max );




int main()
{
    char board[] = "123456789";   // 10 element char board
    const int boardSize = 10;
    Status gameState = CONTINUE;
    int gametype, squareChoice, turnNum = 0;
    char currentSymbol;           // 'o' or 'x'


    cout << "\n This is a Tic Tac Toe program. Choose the type of game: "
         << "\n (1) human o vs. human x    (2) human o vs. dumb computer x"
         << "\n\n -> ";
    cin  >> gametype;


    /* Show the current state of Tic Tac Toe board. */
    cout << gameState;




    /*
       Main game loop
    */
    while ( gameState == CONTINUE )
    {


        /* Increment turnNum by 1. */
        turnNum++;
        /* If turnNum equal to 10
              Set gameState to DRAW.
              Break out of while loop. */
        if ( turnNum = 10 )
        {
            gameState = DRAW;
            break;
        }
        /* If we are on an odd-numbered turn
              Print "It's o's turn."
              Set currentSymbol to 'o'.
              Call getHumanSquare function to get squareChoice.*/
        if ( turnNum%2 != 0)
{
            cout << "It's o's turn.";
            currentSymbol = 'o';

            int getHumanSquare();

            return boardSize;
}

        /* Else (we are on an even-numbered turn)
            Print "It's x's turn."
            Set currentSymbol to 'x'. */
        else
        {
            cout << "It's x's turn.";
            currentSymbol = 'x';
        }


        /*   If the gametype is 1 (human vs. human)
              Call getHumanSquare function to get squareChoice.*/
        if ( gametype == 1 )
{
            int getHumanSquare();

                return boardSize;
}


        /* Else (gametype is 2 (human vs. computer))
           Call getComputerSquare function to get squareChoice. */
        else

            int getComputerSquare();
            {
                return boardSize;
            }


        /* If squareChoice is -1 (human player quit)
              Set gameState to QUIT.*/
        if ( squareChoice == -1 )
        {
            gameState = QUIT;
        }

        /* Else
           Insert currentSymbol into board at (squareChoice - 1).
           Show the current state of the Tic Tac Toe board.
           Call checkGameState function to determine the gameState. */
        else
{
            bool checkBadSquare();
                return boardSize;

            Status checkGameState();
}
    }

    // end while


    /* If gameState is WIN
          print "Player " currentSymbol " is the winner." */
    if ( gameState == WIN)
        cout << "Player " << currentSymbol << " is the winnter.";

    /* If gameState is DRAW
          print "It's a draw." */
    if ( gameState == DRAW )
        cout << "It's a draw.";

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void showBoard( const char board [], int size )
{
    cout << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        cout << board[ i ] << " ";
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 3 == 0 )
            cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Status checkGameState( const char board[] )
{
    // Board       Array
    //
    // 1 2 3       0 1 2
    // 4 5 6  -->  3 4 5
    // 7 8 9       6 7 8
    //
    // Diagonal winners
    if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 0 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 2 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 6 ] )
        return WIN;
    // Horizontal winners
    else if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 1 ] && board[ 1 ] == board[ 2 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 3 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 5 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 6 ] == board[ 7 ] && board[ 7 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    // Vertical winners
    else if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 3 ] && board[ 3 ] == board[ 6 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 1 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 7 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 2 ] == board[ 5 ] && board[ 5 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    else
        // No one has won yet
        return CONTINUE;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getHumanSquare( const char board[] )
{
    int squareNum;

    cout << "\n Input the number of an empty square: (-1 to quit) ";
    cin  >> squareNum;

    while ( checkBadSquare( board, squareNum ) == true )
    {
        cout << "\n Bad input. Choose another square: ";
        cin >> squareNum;
    }

    return squareNum;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getComputerSquare( const char board[] )
{
    int squareNum;

    squareNum = getrandint( 1, 9 );

    while ( checkBadSquare( board, squareNum ) == true )
    {
        squareNum = getrandint( 1, 9 );
    }

    return squareNum;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool checkBadSquare( const char board[], int squareNum )
{
    int realSquareNum = squareNum - 1; // count from 0

    if ( squareNum == -1 )
        return false;  // Let quit code pass as a valid square
    else if ( squareNum > 9 )
        return true;   // Square numbers out of range are invalid
    else if ( board[ realSquareNum ] == 'o' || board[ realSquareNum ] == 'x' )
        return true;   // Already taken squares are invalid
    else
        return false;  // Valid square number
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getrandint( int min, int max )
{

    int scale, shift;
    scale = max - min + 1;
    shift = min;
    return rand() % scale + shift;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I included cstdlib.  i was not aware rand was defined in that library. however now I am having an issue wiht the actual program. after the user chooses either 1 or 2 to play against computer or human the next line that shows is "it's a draw" it skips the whole game. i am not sure why because i set turnNum to 0 and increment by 1 at the beginning of the code. is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the top of your code `#include<cstdlib>`
rand() is defined in that library file.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not aware it was in a different library file. however now I am having a different problem with the code. after the user chooses either 1 or 2 to play against computer or human the next line that shows is "it's a draw" it skips the whole game. is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You can type

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

or

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: Or even better, `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: i used #include <cstdlib> and it worked thank you so much! but now when i run it, it compiles and works but after the user picks 1 or 2(to play against human or computer) it just goes to the it's a draw line. the game doesnt show.however all the code is in my main function. did i perhaps write the coding wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By replying your questions in comments:

You code has several major problems:
1. enum elements index start from 0, so CONTINUE is actually 2. If you input gameType=1, the `while` loop will never get executed. so you have `It is a DRAW`.

1. Several syntax errors:

   ```
   int getHumanSquare(); //are you calling a function or declaring a function?
   return boardSize;


   if ( gametype == 1 )
   {
       int getHumanSquare();  //^^^^^^same issues

           return boardSize;
   }
   else //missing { and } here

       int getComputerSquare();
       {
           return boardSize;
       }
   ```

Several same typed errors below:

```
     bool checkBadSquare();  //same here
     return boardSize;

     Status checkGameState();//same here
```

Comment: I am trying to call a function, the function is defined below the main code. 

I am a little confused what you mean by continue is 2?

Comment: @user2085224 You use enum and CONTINUE is one the member, if you print the value of those enum fields, it will be 2, and draw will be 1, (WIN = 0, DRAW =1, CONTINUE= 2, QUIT =3 ) mapping them to integers. If you call a function, you simply use the name of the function with parameters, you don't need to the return type anymore. For example: getHumanSquare();

Comment: I tried using just the functions, but I am a little lost about what parameters I will use for the functions.

Comment: So if I changed enum to char would it help?

Comment: When calling a function,you need to pass the expected parameters, for example, getComputerSquare (const char board[]), you need to pass an array of const char to it when calling it. enum does not hurt at all. you can input 2, then it will enter the while loop. but other parts of your code has problems, and you will need to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you so much @Song Wang, my program works! Just one quick question. I think my program would be better if I showed what the board looked like after every turn the human takes.  I tried calling the showBoard function but i understand it is a void function.  how would I print something from a void function.  Also when i call it i use showBoard( board, boardSize) but that doesnt work, no matter what variable i put as the second paramater.

Comment: @user2085224 just print the board inside it and pass board as a parameter

Comment: i've tried printing the board in the void showboard function and it didn't work. i still got errors. and i tried it after each turn in the while statement as well. they both don't work because it says I need another paramater but whatever i put in the 2nd paramter does not work.

Comment: @user2085224 try `showBoard( board, size )` in your main, while `board` is the `board` and `size` is size of board

Comment: hmm. it did not work but i typed in boardSize and it worked. I am not sure why it was not working before.  would I be able to save.  I want to save squaresymbol into squarechoice after the user chooses a number, is that possible since squarechoice is integer and squaresymbol is a char